# Last selected value in extjs multiselect combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

How do we get only the last selected value in multiselect combobox and not all the selected values? For example if we select three values 1, 3 and 2, then I want to retrieve 2 as it was selected at last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get the value of combo by using `combo.value` you will see an array that is in order how you selected the combo data from combo Box. This leads you get the last index of `combo.value` will be your required result.

In below code I taken a combo values and displaying the last result.

```
var combo = this.up().down('combo');
                var CoboVal = combo.value;
                var CoboValLength = CoboVal.length;
                if(CoboValLength !== 0){
                    var CoboValData = CoboVal[CoboValLength-1];
                    alert(CoboValData);
                }
```

I created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lcp) for you please check.

Comment: Thanks UDID for ur response. I am applying this code on select event of combobox and it does not gives me the last selected value. Is there any way I can get this value on select event ?

Comment: @Gaurav In select event will give you whatever value you select each at time. well in this case also my answer apply. I updated the fiddler. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks UDID for ur solution  !